# Search for an Array or List in a List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Have

```
List<byte> lbyte
```

Have

```
byte[] searchBytes
```

How can I search lbyte for not just a single byte but for the index of the searchBytes?
E.G.

```
Int32 index = lbyte.FirstIndexOf(searchBytes);
```

Here is the brute force I came up with.
Not the performance I am looking for.

```
public static Int32 ListIndexOfArray(List<byte> lb, byte[] sbs)
{
    if (sbs == null) return -1;
    if (sbs.Length == 0) return -1;
    if (sbs.Length > 8) return -1;
    if (sbs.Length == 1) return lb.FirstOrDefault(x => x == sbs[0]);
    Int32 sbsLen = sbs.Length;
    Int32 sbsCurMatch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lb.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lb[i] == sbs[sbsCurMatch])
        {
            sbsCurMatch++;
            if (sbsCurMatch == sbsLen)
            {
                //int index = lb.FindIndex(e => sbs.All(f => f.Equals(e)));  // fails to find a match
                IndexOfArray = i - sbsLen + 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            sbsCurMatch = 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @YairNevet a List of byte

Comment: @YairNevet another list of bytes, this is essentially orderedlist.containssequence there must be a good solution here as its essentially solved with string.contains but this is a more generic case

Comment: Try looking [here](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=79) for an extension method to do this.

Comment: Are you sure your brute force method is correct? Looks like it's not checking the last character of the search string. So when looking for "frob", if only checks "fro". I think you want to increment `sbsCurMatch` *after* the length check. As it stands, it will fail on a one-character string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) useful here. Convert your list to an array and search. The algorithm code is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890164/187697).

```
static int SimpleBoyerMooreSearch(byte[] haystack, byte[] needle)
{
    int[] lookup = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < lookup.Length; i++) { lookup[i] = needle.Length; }

    for (int i = 0; i < needle.Length; i++)
    {
        lookup[needle[i]] = needle.Length - i - 1;
    }

    int index = needle.Length - 1;
    var lastByte = needle.Last();
    while (index < haystack.Length)
    {
        var checkByte = haystack[index];
        if (haystack[index] == lastByte)
        {
            bool found = true;
            for (int j = needle.Length - 2; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (haystack[index - needle.Length + j + 1] != needle[j])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found)
                return index - needle.Length + 1;
            else
                index++;
        }
        else
        {
            index += lookup[checkByte];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You can then search like this. If `lbyte` will remain constant after a certain time, you can just convert it to an array once and pass that.

```
//index is returned, or -1 if 'searchBytes' is not found
int startIndex = SimpleBoyerMooreSearch(lbyte.ToArray(), searchBytes);
```

Update based on comment. Here's the `IList` implementation which means that arrays and lists (and anything else that implements `IList` can be passed)

```
 static int SimpleBoyerMooreSearch(IList<byte> haystack, IList<byte> needle)
 {
    int[] lookup = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < lookup.Length; i++) { lookup[i] = needle.Count; }

    for (int i = 0; i < needle.Count; i++)
    {
        lookup[needle[i]] = needle.Count - i - 1;
    }

    int index = needle.Count - 1;
    var lastByte = needle[index];
    while (index < haystack.Count)
    {
        var checkByte = haystack[index];
        if (haystack[index] == lastByte)
        {
            bool found = true;
            for (int j = needle.Count - 2; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (haystack[index - needle.Count + j + 1] != needle[j])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found)
                return index - needle.Count + 1;
            else
                index++;
        }
        else
        {
            index += lookup[checkByte];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Since arrays and lists implement IList, there's no conversion necessary when calling it in your case.

```
int startIndex = SimpleBoyerMooreSearch(lbyte, searchBytes);
```

Comment: You may be able to switch out your byte arrays with [`IList`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) to make your code more generic

Comment: Unfotunalely the List changes with each call.  I don't yet follow this but I will give it a try.  If you implement the IList version please post it here.

Comment: @Blam - I've added the IList version. It's not fully generic (only accepts bytes) but it should work in your case as it handles lists and arrays of bytes.

Comment: I am too tired to follow it right now but I will test it out.

Comment: @Blam - This post may help explain the algorithm itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207819/boyer-moore-algorithm-understanding-and-example

Comment: @keyboardP As I read that explanation it is the same brute force I came up with but my code is nothing like your code.

Comment: @Blam: B-M is not a brute force algorithm. The gist of B-M is that you can skip up to *m* characters (bytes) when a mismatch occurs, your code always skips only 1 which makes it slower by an order of magnitude. Since your case is basically a substring search (i.e. order is important, values are not unique, isn't sorted) then B-M is the fastest solution.

Comment: @BorisB. I just don't follow.  If I am searching the string 'caacattdog' for 'cat' how can I skip going from either direction and not miss a match?

Comment: @Blam - B-M scans backwards so if you're searching for `cat`, `t` is the first to be checked. Since `t` does not match with `a` (3rd character) you can skip the first 3 characters (length of search pattern). Now, `t` matches `t` (6th char), `a` matches `a` and `c` matches `c`. Or Working from the end of the string, `t` doesn't match `g`, so skip to `length - 3`. `t` matches `t` but `a` doesn't match `t` (6th char). However, since `t` exists in search string, you move down 1 so that the search string `t` aligns with the 6th char `t`. There you have your match. These skips improve performance.

Comment: @Blam - I'm not an expert on the B-M algorithm but that's how I understand it to work. Happy to be corrected if I'm wrong about it.

Comment: @OK I finally get it +1  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Brute force is always an option. Although slow in comparison to some other methods, in practice it's usually not too bad. It's easy to implement and quite acceptable if `lbyte` isn't huge and doesn't have pathological data.

It's the same concept as [brute force string searching](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/03/27/computer-algorithms-brute-force-string-matching/).

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do with lambda expression

```
int index = lbyte.FindIndex(e => searchBytes.All(i => i.Equals(e));
```

Comment: Missing  ) and I tested it does not find matches.

Comment: Would you please write your test case ?

Comment: I added where I am testing it to the code I posted in the question.  I don't really have a "test case" to produce data.  I am reading those bytes from a database.  But I know the brute force is matching properly.