# Boyer-Moore good-suffix heuristics

Tags: c, algorithm, boyer-moore

I understand how the bad character heuristics work. When you find the mismatched letter `x`, just shift the pattern so the rightmost `x` in the pattern would be aligned with the `x` in the string. And it's easy to implement in code.

I think I also understand how the good-suffix heuristics work. When we find a good suffix `s`, find the same suffix in different location in the pattern and shift it so the `s` in the pattern would be aligned with the `s` in the string. But I don't understand how to do that in code. How do we find if the same suffix exists in another place in pattern? And how do we know its position? The code:

```
void bmPreprocess1()
{
    int i=m, j=m+1;
    f[i]=j;
    while (i>0)
    {
        while (j<=m && p[i-1]!=p[j-1])
        {
            if (s[j]==0) s[j]=j-i;
            j=f[j];
        }
        i--; j--;
        f[i]=j;
    }
}
```

from http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/bmen.htm doesn't make sense to me... Could someone write as simple as possible pseudo code for this task? Or explain somehow?

Comment: If you any questions, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, I will use `p[i]` denote a character in the pattern, `m` the pattern lenght, `$` the last character in the pattern, i.e., `$ = p[m-1]`.

There are two situations for good suffix heuristics case 1.

**Situation 1**

Consider the following example,

```
    leading TEXT cXXXbXXXcXXXcXXX rest of the TEXT
         cXXXbXXXcXXXcXXX
                     ^ 
                     | mismatch here
```

So the sub string `XXX` in the pattern `cXXXbXXXcXXXcXXX` is the good suffix. The mismatch occurs at character `c`. So after the mismatch, should we shift 4 to the right or 8?

If we shift 4 as in the following, then the same mismath will occur again (`b` mismathes `c`),

```
    leading TEXT cXXXbXXXcXXXcXXX rest of the TEXT
             cXXXbXXXcXXXcXXX
                     ^ 
                     | mismatch occurs here again
```

So we can actually shift 8 characters to the right in this situation.

**Situation 2**

Let us look at another example

```
    leading TEXT cXXXcXXXbXXXcXXX rest of the TEXT
            cXXXXcXXXbXXXcXXX
                         ^ 
                         | mismatch happens here
```

Can we shift 4 or 8 or more here? Obviously we if we shift 8 or more, we will miss the opportunity to match the pattern with the text. So we can only shift 4 characters to the right in this situation.

So what is the difference between these two situations?

The difference is that in the first case, the mismatched character `c` plus the good suffix `XXX`, which is `cXXX`, is the same as the next (count from the right) match for `XXX` plus the character before that.  While in the second situation, `cXXX` is not the same as the next match (count from the right) plus the character before that match.

So for any given GOOD SUFFIX (let us call it `XXX`) we need to figure out the shift in these two situations, (1) the character (let us call it `c`) before the GOOD SUFFIX plus the GOOD SUFFIX, in the pattern is also match the next (count from the right) match of the good suffix + the character before it , (2) the character plus the GOOD SUFFIX does not match

For situation (1), for example,  if you have a pattern, `0XXXcXXXcXXXcXXXcXXXcXXX`, if after the first test of `c` fails, you can shift 20 characters to the right, and align `0XXX` with the text that been tested.

This is how the number 20 is calculated,

```
              1         2
    012345678901234567890123
    0XXXcXXXcXXXcXXXcXXXcXXX
    ^                   ^
```

The position the mismatch occurs is 20, the shifted sub string `0XXX` will take position from 20 to 23. And `0XXX` starts with position 0, so 20 - 0 = 20.

For situation (2), like in this example, `0XXXaXXXbXXXcXXX`, if after the first test of `c` fails, you can shift only 4 characters to the right, and align `bXXX` with the text that been tested.

This is how number `4` is calculated,

```
    0123456789012345
    0XXXaXXXbXXXcXXX
```

The position where the mismatch occurs is 12,  the next substring to take that place is `bXXX` which starts with position 8, 12 - 8 = 4. If we set `j = 12`, and `i = 8`, then the shift is `j - i`, which is `s[j] = j - i;` in the code.

**Border**

To consider all the good suffix, we first need to understand what is a so called `border`.
A border is a substring which is both a `proper` prefix and a `proper` suffix of a string. For example, for a string `XXXcXXX`, `X` is a border, `XX` is a border, `XXX` too. But `XXXc` is not. We need to identify the starting point of the widest border of the suffix of the pattern and this info is saved in array `f[i]`.

How to determine `f[i]` ?

Assume we know `f[i] = j` and for all other `f[k]`s with `i < k < m`, which means the widest border for the suffix starting from position `i` started at position `j`.   We want to find `f[i-1]` based on `f[i]`.

For example, for a pattern `aabbccaacc`, at postion `i=4`, the suffix is `ccaacc`, and the widest border for that is `cc` (`p[8]p[9]`), so `j = f[i=4] = 8`. And now we want to know `f[i-1] = f[3]` based on the info we have for `f[4]`, `f[5]`, ...   For `f[3]`, the suffix now is `bccaacc`. At position, `j-1=7`, it is `a` != `p[4-1]` which is `b`. So `bcc` is not a border.

We know any border with width >= 1 of `bccaacc` has to begin with `b` plus the border of the suffix starting from positin `j = 8`, which is `cc` in this example. `cc` has the widest border `c` at position `j = f[8]` which is `9`.  So we continue our search with comparing `p[4-1]` against `p[j-1]`. And they are not equal again. Now the suffix is `p[9] = c` and it has only zero length border  at position `10`. so now `j = f[9]` and it is `10`. So we continue our search with comparing `p[4-1]` against `p[j-1]`, they are not equal and that is the end of the string.  Then `f[3]` has only zero length border which make it equal to 10.

**To describe the process in a more general sense**

Therefore, `f[i] = j` means something like this,

```
    Position:    012345     i-1  i     j - 1   j       m
    pattern:     abcdef ... @    x ... ?       x ...   $
```

If character `@` at position `i - 1` is the same as character `?` at position `j - 1`, we know that
`f[i - 1] = j - 1;` , or  `--i; --j; f[i] = j;`.  The border is suffix `@x ... $` starting from position `j-1`.

But if character `@` at position `i - 1` is different from character `?` at position `j - 1`,
we have to continue our search to the right. We know two facts:  (1) we know now the border width has to be smaller than the one started from position `j`, i.e, smaller than `x...$`. Second the border has to be begin with `@...` and ends with character `$` or it could be empty.

Based on these two facts, we continue our search within sub string `x ... $` (from position j to m) for a border begin with `x`.  Then the next border should be at `j` which is equal to  `f[j];`, i.e. `j = f[j];`. Then we compare character `@` with the character before `x`, which is at `j-1`. If they are equal, we found the border, if not, continue the process until j > m.    This process is shown by the following code,

```
    while (j<=m && p[i-1]!=p[j-1])
    {
        j=f[j];
    }

    i--; j--;
    f[i]=j;
```

Now look at condition `p[i -1] !=` p[j-1]`, this is what we talked about in situation (2),` p[i]`matches`p[j]`, but` p[i -1] != `p[j-1]`, so we shift from `i` to `j`, that that is `s[j] = j - i;`.

Now the only thing left not explained is the test `if (s[j] == 0)` which will occur when a shorter suffix has the same border. For example, you have a pattern

```
    012345678
    addbddcdd
```

When you calculate `f[i - 1]` and `i = 4`, you will set `s[7]`. But when you calculate `f[i-1]` for `i = 1`, you will set `s[7]` again if you don't have the test `if (s[j] == 0)`. This means if you have mismatch at position `6`, you shift `3` to the right (align `bdd` to the positions `cdd` occupied) not `6` (not shift until `add` to the positions `cdd` occupied).

**The comments for the code**

```
    void bmPreprocess1()
    {
        // initial condition, set f[m] = m+1;
        int i=m, j=m+1;
        
        f[i]=j;

        // calculate f[i], s[j] from i = m to 0.
        while (i>0)
        {
            // at this line, we know f[i], f[i+1], ... f[m].
            while (j<=m && p[i-1]!=p[j-1]) // calculate the value of f[i-1] and save it to j-1
            {
                if (s[j]==0) s[j]=j-i; // if s[j] is not occupied, set it.
                j=f[j]; // get the start position of the border of suffix p[j] ... p[m-1]
            }
            // assign j-1 to f[i-1]
            i--; j--;
            f[i]=j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 . One question : "We know any border with width >= 1 of bccaacc has to begin with b plus the border of the suffix starting from positin j = 8" , what is intuition behind it , i understood that it should start with b but how can we simply jump to f[8] here ?

Comment: I mean i can think that f(3) can be derived from f(4) but how it can  use f(5) , f(6) ... ? , especially this code segment 
"while (j<=m && p[i-1]!=p[j-1])
    {
        j=f[j];
    }"
how this intuition j=f[j] ?

Comment: Since we already determine that `bcc` is not a border, we have to find the borders of border `cc` because a border is both a prefix and a suffix.  The reason f(3) need f(5) ... is the same reason. If the current border does not work, we need to find the border of the current border.

Comment: Thanks for quick response : let me nail down my doubt to point ,
when we find that p[j-1]!=p[i-1] why dont i simply check p[i-1] equality with p[m-1] instead of your logic of checking p[i-1] with p[p[j]-1] iteratively.can you please provide any test case where my logic fails .. I am very sorry if i miss the base logic .

Comment: One such example would be `012dabdabcabdab`. Now consider `f(3)`.

Comment: Thanks John , that string was really helpful for clear my doubt .

Comment: How many explanations could have been left out if people could do better than single letter variable names...

Comment: Shouldn't this sentence "so we shift from i to j, that that is s[j] = j - i;" be changed to "so we shift from j to i, that that is s[j] = j - i;"? since when you are comparing pattern with the text, you are comparing backward?

Comment: @Backrub32 , here we talk about shifting the string `p[I]` for the scenario 2 of good suffix heuristics case 1. You can check the explanation in that section.